# how to cut Faces after detection

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have been working on a college project using OpenCV. I made a simple program which detects faces, by passing frames captured by a webcam in a function which detects faces.

On detection it draws black boxes on the faces when detected. However my project does not end here, i would like to be able to clip out those faces which get detected as soon as possible and save it in an image and then apply different image processing techniques [as per my need]. If this is too problematic i could use a simple image instead of using  frames captured by a webcam.

I am just clueless about how to go about clipping those faces out that get detected.

Comment: When you say detected -- what are they detected as?  In other words have you segmented the image, and have a set of pixels, or is there some analytical means which only produces a true/false value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++ version you can check [this tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) from OpenCV documentation.

In the function `detectAndDisplay` you can see the line

```
Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
```

where `faceROI` is clipped face and you can save it to file with `imwrite` function:

```
imwrite("face.jpg", faceROI);
```

Answer (score 1):

[http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_(ROI)](http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_%28ROI%29)

Check this link, you can crop the image using the dimensions of the black box, resize it and save as a new file.

Comment: @VJo You need to manually add the closing paren to the end of the URL. Seems to be a bug in SO's auto-formatting.

Comment: you are right SSteve, I did not notice that. @Vjo, just copy paste the url.

Answer (score 0):

Could you grab the frame and crop the photo with the X,Y coordinates of each corner?

Comment: Webcam would capture moving objects wont it? So how do i get those co-ordinates?